# Local Content severed over HTTP / HTTPS

Tags: html, http, dom

Within HTML if the entire site is served over HTTPS, and it makes reference to the following:

`<img src="../images/Sexy_Ben.jpeg" />`

Does that mean that the file in question will be served over HTTP or HTTPS?

Thanks,

Comment: It's a relative link, so https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS, relative paths use the same protocol that the HTML page was loaded with.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.